# Linq How to create relationship include for many to many relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

Hi I have linq query like below.

```
var vendors = (from v in dbContext.Vendors
                   where v.StatusID == (int)StatusEnum.Inactive
                   select new
                   {
                      vendor = v,
                      Contractors = v.Contractors,
                      User = v.User,
                      EmailTransactions = v.User.EmailTransactions.Where(et => emailCategories.Any(ec => ec == et.CategoryID) && et.SentDate >= v.InactiveDate)
                   }).AsEnumerable().Select(v => v.v)
```

the above query return vendor records and I can see "vendor.User" & "vendor.User.EmailTransactions" is projected correctly.

but, for vendor.Contractors, return empty result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you share entities ?

Comment: Make sure you have data. You can also [log the generated SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) to debug.

Comment: Hi, yes I am sure I have the data..

Comment: In the final select you are selecting only v from v, therefore your code does not compile.

Comment: I dont think it was the problem. since ef will automatically mapping the relation. For example, with this code, I can see vendor.user & vendor.user.EmailTransactions was mapping correctly.